# How to prevent Excel from automatically adding workbook name to named ranges?

Tags: excel

I have a dashboard that uses a named range for a pivot table in Excel 2013. When I save the workbook with a new name, Excel is adding the previous workbook name to the pivot table data source. It looks something like this:

- Pivot data source in Dashboardv2: PivotData
- Pivot data source after saving the workbook as Dashboardv3: 'Dashboardv2'!PivotData

The named range is an offset formula that references a tabular dataset. I have a different dashboard that uses a very similar formula and I don't have this issue. I would like to be able to save the workbook with a different name while still utilizing the named ranges if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: Don't think that's possible. Named ranges are tied to their respective workbooks. How else would you know which it is?

Comment: Agree with @findwindow - keep in mind that 2 workbooks could have ranges with identical names; the workbook qualifier is required to avoid issues with duplicate names.

Comment: Perhaps I did not communicate my problem well. The issue is that when you save the workbook with a new name, the pivot table tries to reference the old workbook, instead of the correct sheet/named range in the new workbook. It appears this is a known issue: http://bit.ly/1XZZliq

I was able to get around the issue by scoping the name only to a specific sheet.

Comment: I guess I didn't fix it. The issue doesn't happen immediately after making changes, but as soon as the workbook is closed and the reopened the issue reappears.